# adding new object to an object array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

A newbie to react, I have been trying to add new object to an object array but I couldn't update,

In form jsx, 'items' have been used as props from home jsx, I have to add new object to item array.

```
import './form.css';

import { useState } from 'react';


function Form({items}){
    
    const [elements,setElements] = useState(items);
    const [title,setTitle] = useState("");
    const [content,setContent] = useState("");
   
    function Submit(e){
        
        
        e.preventDefault();
        
        setElements(prevItems=>  [...prevItems,{title:title,content:content}]);
       
        
      
    }
    function handleTitleChange(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        setTitle(e.target.value);
    }
    function handleContentChange(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        setContent(e.target.value);
    }
    return(
    <form onSubmit={Submit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleTitleChange}  placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea onChange={handleContentChange}  placeholder="Take a note"/>
        <button type='submit'>+</button>
    </form>);
}

export default Form;



function Home(){
    const items = [{
        
        title:"Loops",
        content:"Its a iterative statement"
    }];
    return(

       
        <Fragment >
            <Form items = {items}/>
            <Cards items={items}/>
            
        </Fragment>
    );
    
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to make `items` state and remove the `elements` state. You can pass the `items` state setter function into your `Form` component if you want to change it from there. It's a bit hard to tell what your actual issue is or what you're trying to do though.

Comment: You are creating duplicate of your item state in the Form component and adding new items to copy of that state. You need to change the original state present in the Home component.

Comment: See: [Sharing state between components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) from React's docs for further info on how to "lift your state up".

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in creating dynamic fields of the form

```
function Form({items}){
    
    const [elements,setElements] = useState(items);
    // No need to use `title` and `content` for every field
    /*const [title,setTitle] = useState("");
    const [content,setContent] = useState("");*/
   
    function Submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //setElements(prevItems=>  [...prevItems,{title:title,content:content}]);
    }
    function handleTitleChange(val, index){
        // update the `title` value in state by each `index`
        const newElements = [...elements];
        newElements[index].title = val

        setElements(newElements);
    }
    function handleContentChange(val, index){
        // update the `content` value in state by each `index`
        const newElements = [...elements];
        newElements[index].content = val

        setElements(newElements);
    }
    return(
    <form onSubmit={Submit}>
      <!-- render each field dynamically through `map` -->
      {elements.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleTitleChange(e.target.value, index)} placeholder="Title" value={item.title} />
              <textarea onChange={(e) => handleContentChange(e.target.value, index)} placeholder="Take a note" value={item.content}/>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        <button type='submit'>+</button>
    </form>);
}

export default Form;
```